# Sprinkler controller: Can one field zone wire be 'doubled' and used on two controller zones?

Tags: wiring

Is it possible to hook up the same sprinkler field zone wire into two different controller zone slots?

I just bought a replacement sprinkler controller believing it had the same multiple watering options as the timer it replaced.  It doesn't.  I don't want to hassle returning and replacing it right now. Eventually I will get one that does what I want, but for now I was wondering if I can make use of the empty zones on the controller to have more watering options.

It's a rainbird SST 6-zone.  I have two control wires, each in their own slot, and three zone wires, one each in slots 1,2,3.  Slots 4,5,6 are empty.  All working correctly.

What I'd like to do is send the zone 1 field wire to both slot 1 and slot 4, the zone 2 field wire to slot 2 and slot 5, and the zone 3 field wire to slot 3 and slot 6?  If I can do this, then I can program 1,2,3 for morning waterings and 4,5,6 for night waterings, something the controller can't do for me now because the max hours interval to second watering is 12 hours and it isn't enough.

The controller states it will not water more than one zone at a time no matter the settings, so I think I'm OK that the controller will not try to open the same valves from two different zones.

Is this even possible?  Is this a really stupid idea?

Comment: Might work, draw up a schematic for the valves

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work. Simply jumper the wire from one controller zone to the other as you propose. Even if the controller could turn on more than one zone at a time it wouldn't matter since they share a common power source.

Comment: just don't reverse the wires for the 24Vac out

Comment: Not a worry - they use a common line for all zones.

Comment: Three jumper wires!  I can do this!  I'm such a noob.  Thank you so much!  I voted as answer but I have no reputation to make it count, sorry :-)